# How to get specific XML data from this?

Tags: android

I am trying to get a value from an XML file from sdcard.
I have no idea to get this value I figured in the picture.

Please help me. Thank you !

[image: xml view]

Comment: Open the XML file and parse it.

Comment: have you able to get it from sdCard?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: I am new to android programming. Could you please make full example?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin !yes . I put it to sdcard .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code:-

```
try {
         File file = new File("mnt/sdcard/Backup_Apps/call_logs/calllog_35777569.xml");
         InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(is));
         doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

         NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("map");

         for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

             Node node = nodeList.item(i);

             Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

             System.out.println(fstElmnt.getAttribute("pwd"));

         }

     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
     }
```

see below link:-

[how to parse xml file from Sdcard in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967896/how-to-parse-xml-file-from-sdcard-in-android)

http://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/07/05/xamarin-reading-xml-file-from-sd-card-in-android/

Comment: Hi . . Your answer helps me a lot. It nearly makes me perfect. But I think your code to finding "pwd" not working enough. It can't show me anything. But a.xml is successfully loaded by yours. I also added externalstorage read permission to manifest. But it can't still work. If you don't mind , Could I make send my code (Really a little) to you with a.xml. Thank you so much for Helping me.

Comment: I have thank you a lot! My problem is fixed by your answer. I only needed to change a bit of code.
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("string");
System.out.println(fstElmnt.getTextContent());
Thank you so so much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read the external file from below code :

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File yourFile = new File(dir, "path/to/the/file/inside/the/sdcard.ext");
```

And after that you can use XMLParser available in android to get the required data. Go through [Parsing XML Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

Comment: I am new to android programming. Could you please make some code to get the required data to my textview1 ?

Comment: I will suggest that you go through these tutorials they are very useful for beginners and it covers all basics : http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/android-tutorial/